# Resultados intermitentes...tem limite de JOIN no PHP?

Tags: php

Eu escolho a montadora do carro, o modelo, motor e ano e realizo a consulta assim:

```html
 $query = "SELECT b.montadora, m.modelo, n.motor, a.ano, d.descricao, c.combustivel, f.f_cabine, g.local_ar_cabine, h.f_ar, j.f_lub_princ, k.f_lub_opcional, l.f_combustivel FROM 13_tecfil t
    JOIN 0_montadora b
    ON t.montadora = b.id
     JOIN 1_modelo m
     ON t.modelo = m.id
      JOIN 2_motor n
      ON t.motor = n.id
       JOIN 3_ano a
       ON t.ano = a.id
        JOIN 4_descricao d
        ON t.descricao = d.id
         JOIN 5_combustivel c
         ON t.combustivel = c.id
          JOIN 6_f_cabine f
          ON t.f_cabine = f.id
           JOIN 7_local_ar_cabine g
           ON t.local_ar_cabine = g.id
            JOIN 8_f_ar h
            ON t.f_ar = h.id
             JOIN 9_f_lub_princ j
             ON t.f_lub_princ = j.id
              JOIN 10_f_lub_opcional k
              ON t.f_lub_opcional = k.id
               JOIN 11_f_combustivel l
               ON t.f_combustivel = l.id
                WHERE t.montadora = '". $_POST['id_montadora'] ."' AND
                t.modelo = '". $_POST['id_modelo'] ."' AND
                t.motor = '". $_POST['id_motor'] ."' AND
                t.ano = '". $_POST['id_ano'] ."'
                ORDER BY b.montadora";
 $result_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Porém, tem carros que a consulta retorna dados e tem carros que retorna NULL.
O caso é que se eu reduzir a consulta para apenas aparecer os índices assim:

```html
 $query = "SELECT * FROM 13_tecfil
    WHERE montadora = '". $_POST['id_montadora'] ."' AND
    modelo = '". $_POST['id_modelo'] ."' AND
    motor = '". $_POST['id_motor'] ."' AND
    ano = '". $_POST['id_ano'] ."'
    ORDER BY montadora";
 $result_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Os carros que antes não retornava nada, retorna dados agora, apesar de ser apenas índices.
Existe alguma restrição de JOIN no PHP? Como posso fazer a primeira consulta de forma que funcione?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom...consegui achar o problema.
Algumas tabelas minhas as chaves primárias poderiam ser em branco, teoricamente.
O problema é que o valor ficava *NULL* e dava problema na consulta.
Resolvi alterando esses valores vazios para uma chave estrangeira "-" e *voilá*...

Answer (score 3):

Para MySQL existe um limite de 61 tabelas ou 4096 colunas.

No seu caso precisaria de um dump do banco para avaliar os relacionamentos. Provavelmente alguma chave estrangeira aí pode não estar batendo.

A coluna "id" da 13_tecfil está presente em todas as tabelas?

Se for o caso dela ser opcional em alguma delas, experimente um `FULL OUTER JOIN`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql

Comment: *Valeu, não sabia desses limites!

*É estranho as chaves não estar funcionando, vi pelo BD e parece tudo OK, além do mais é um problema em algumas consultas, outras funcionam...

*Sim, a coluna ID de cada tabela está presente na 13_tecfil.

*Ok, vou tentar outro modo...